# php session variable randomly changes

Tags: php, session, web, session-variables, session-state

I have a website that has a membership system. When users log in, I validate username/password from the database and start a session, $_SESSION['userid'] that contains their id (I have not implemented anything using cookies yet)

I have a problem, the system works fine most of the times, but some users have reported that they eventually find themselves logged in to some other random users account. That probably means that $_SESSION['userid'] changes without any reason to something else and I'm pretty sure I'm not doing anything to change it.

Any ideas why this could be happening ?

edit : Summary of what I am doing

This method start the session

```
function startSession($id){
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;
$_SESSION['userid'] = $id;
}
```

This method checks login

```
function isLoggedIn(){ 
    return isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && isset($_SESSION['userid']) && $_SESSION['userid']!=" " && $_SESSION['logged_in']==1;
}
```

This is the logout method

```
function logout(){
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['userid'] = 0;
    unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);
    unset($_SESSION['userid']);
    session_destroy();
    if (!isLoggedIn()){ return "S3"; }
    else { return "E3"; }
}
```

And this is how I check if the user is logged in most places

```
if (isLoggedIn()){ $profileid = $_SESSION['userid']; }
```

This is the login function, this is where I call startSession

```
function login($username, $password){
    $pdo = newPDO();
    $username = sanitize_string($username);
    $password = sha1(sanitize_string($password));
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM ".TABLE_PROFILE." WHERE nick=:nick AND pass=:pass LIMIT 1");
    $query->execute(array(':nick'=>$username, ':pass'=>$password));
    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (count($result['id']) == 1){ 
        startSession($result['id']);
        loginExecution();
        return "S1";
    }
    else{ return "E1"; }
}
```

Comment: You will need to post your code for all the pages you're using. There are too many possible reasons.

Comment: @Fred-ii- there are thousands of lines of codes in different files. I just need opinnions of what could go wrong ^^

Comment: The problem is not on SESSION, the problem in your login script. Please publish the script if you want to get correct solution

Comment: Hmpph, weird. Maybe a still active session id was assigned to another user. When another user get the same session id they will have control over that account. But this is unlikely to happen if the session id is not set manually.

Comment: It's too hard for "me" to say. Usually a session is assigned from a `$_POST` variable, and for example `$user=$_POST['user']; $_SESSION['user'] = $user;` type of thing. If anything else changes beyond that, or you've assigned it to a column/row, then that could be a factor.

Comment: added some codes form the script

Comment: And try setting cookie expiry to some date in the past so the cookie expires when the session expires.

Comment: Please, publish the script, where you call *startSession* function

Comment: @Dmitriy.Net just added that part at the end ^^

Comment: The space in `$_SESSION['userid']!=" "` could be a factor. @OguzGelal which should read as `$_SESSION['userid']!=""`

Comment: @Fred-ii- thats not it, I added that part after the problem occured :(

Comment: @Dmitriy.Net I don't think the problem lies within the codes, because OguzGelal mentioned it didn't happen all the time.

Comment: Where else is `$id` being used/defined besides in your `startSession()` function? @OguzGelal

Comment: @Dmitriy.Net yeah, it doesn't ALLWAYS happen and it doesn't happen to everyone

Comment: @iamsleepy, yes, it's probleb with incoming data

Comment: @Fred-ii- That startSession() fucntion is the only place I set the SESSION data

Comment: `$id` needs to be defined/assigned somewhere else in order to be active, yes? @OguzGelal

Comment: @iamsleepy yeah, it is given with incoming data from the user. And the users that doesn't even know eachother faces this problem so it is not possible that they are using the same computer or something :(

Comment: Are you getting high traffic nowadays ?

Comment: @iamsleepy not that high, there are about 150 members and 1.5k hits (~600 unique)

Comment: consistency of ID values are broken? some duplicated ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- $id is an argument, it is sent thru login() function ^^

Comment: @sim which ID values ?

Comment: @OguzGelal in "table_profile" field ID contains unique values? nick + pass also must be unique pair.

Comment: Sorry, I can only come up with the idea of duplicate session id assigned by php, although its almost impossible to happen. Good luck tho.

Comment: @sim yes, id field is set to Auto Increnment, there are only unique ID's

Comment: @OguzGelal in this case i'd recommend you to add some debug information which you can use to find your bug.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your login function

Your script is not checking username and password for any data, and if the username and password is empty or incorrect, your client will gets the firs available id from database.

```
function login($username, $password){
    $pdo = newPDO();
    $username = sanitize_string($username);
    $password = sanitize_string($password);

    // Check data for existing
    if (empty($username)) throw new Exeption('Empty username');
    if (empty($password)) throw new Exeption('Empty password');

    $password = sha1($password);

    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM ".TABLE_PROFILE." WHERE nick=:nick AND pass=:pass LIMIT 1");
    $query->execute(array(':nick'=>$username, ':pass'=>$password));
    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (count($result['id']) == 1){ 
        startSession($result['id']);
        loginExecution();
        return "S1";
    }
    else{ return "E1"; }
}
```

P.s. Always check incoming data, before SQL queries

Comment: I call the login function from another script that is called by ajax, and that is where I check if the username and pass is set. Here is the code for that:

if ( isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
 $logged = login($_POST['username'] , $_POST['password']);
 echo getMessage($logged); 
} 
else{ 
 echo getMessage("E5");
}

Comment: Javascript validation is very bad idea for authorization form, because if clients disabled the javascript in browser, validation doesn't work

Comment: in my opinion TS definitely must test input args, but anyway if args are empty the query will return an empty set, i suppose that table does not contain rows with empty data.

Comment: isset function return true, if the login is "space". You must to check using empty function

Comment: True, the space thing will return true at isset(). But these don't explain the mind-blowing fact that session id magically changes :D any ideas on that ?

Comment: My opinion, the problem is not on session, if you not redeclare userid on another functions) Do you reproduce it ?

Comment: @Dmitriy.Net Not sure what you mean by reproduce but $_SESSION['userid'] is only set at sessionStart function and it is only user to check whether if the user is logged in. Nothing else whatsoever

Answer (score -1):

Realistically the only thing I can think of that would cause this is something setting $_SESSION['userid'] to another members id. Assuming this is what you are using to check which members information to show. Are you perhaps doing something if the $_SESSION['userid'] variable is not set that may end up setting $_SESSION['userid'] incorrectly? i.e. if their php session is reset.